# Call EJB method

Tags: java, ejb

Sorry for my English.

I have EJB:

```
public class CtrlEJB extends CtrlImplEJB
{

 .....

 public SaleModel doSale(SaleModel sale) throws ValidationException
 {
    log.info("test");
    return new SaleModel();
 }

 .....

}
```

When I call doSale method remotely, I get error on server:

```
ERROR [:LogInterceptor:RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] RuntimeException in method: public abstract SaleModel CtrlEJB.doSale(SaleModel) throws ValidationException, java.rmi.RemoteException
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:324)
    at org.jboss.ejb.StatefulSessionContainer$ContainerInterceptor.invoke(StatefulSessionContainer.java:982)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.SecurityInterceptor.invoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:186)
    ...
```

Other methods in this class works successfully. 
Please help. Thanks You!

Comment: Did you add the parameter `sale` recently? I guess the client that calls the method depends on an old version of the interface, where the parameter was absent.

Comment: From client I call:

ctrl.doSale(sale); 

sale is instance of SaleModel.